# How can I find iOS games that support the new Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center

Now that the Apple Game Center has opened the gates, where/how can I find games that support these new features? Searching the App Store shows me many games, but not specifically those which are interlinked with the Game Center..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an icon devoted to it in the *Featured* tab in the App Store. While that may disappear in the future, you can also find a section under *Hot New Games*.

Judging by how long *Made for iOS 4* has lasted under *Hot New Games*, this is likely where you'll always want to look for *Game Center*-enabled games.

Comment: This looks good, I didn't look there before. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In the Game Center app, there is an button to find Game Center enabled games. Also, the main view in Game Center shows several games as well. (I assume the ones shown are popular games, but I don't know what criteria defines which apps are shown there.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [forum thread on TouchArcade](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?threadid=65946) that is attempting to list all Game Center-capable apps.

As of 9 Sep 2010, the list was:

- Ace Tennis 2010 Online
- Adrenaline Golf Online
- Azkend
- Bomber Online
- Cannon Challenge 2
- Cocoto Kart Online
- Cocoto Magic Circus
- Cro-Mag Rally
- DinoSmash Online
- Doodle Squares HD
- Enigmo
- Enigmo 2
- Farmville by Zynga
- Field Fencer
- Field Runners
- Flight Control
- GraalOnline Classic
- GraalOnline Classic+
- Icarus-X
- Isaac Newton’s Gravity
- Megaplex Madness - Now Playing
- Ms. Pac-Man
- Nanosaur 2
- Pac-Man
- Real Racing
- reMovem
- Scramble: Challenge Edition by Zynga
- Touchgrind
- World Series of Poker Hold'em Legend
- WordsWorth
- Worldy Wings
- Zen Bound 2 Universal
- Zentomino

Answer (score 0):

If the store doesn't have an ad-hoc search option, chances are searching the store for "game center" is as close as you can get – I imagine the store search includes app description, which will mention the centre once it's supported.

Comment: That's the search term I did use, but this results in nearly any game ...